# Extracting IP addresses with at least 3 conversation in *Nix environment

Tags: perl, unix, awk, text-processing

As seen in the picture, we have a list of IP addresses (Please note that 128.3.* and 131.243.*) are inside our subnet. We prefer to do it in Perl, any other good ideas more than welcome in *nix environment.

The pictures is formatted as:

> Destination IP(sorted)- Dest_Port
>   - Source IP- Source_Port

space is used as a separator.

We were doing it manually but know we have huge files and want to automate this procedure.

> The problem is we need to get the
>   destination IP addresses (**not in our subnet**, not 128.3.* and 131.243.*) which are
>   communicated with at least 3 different
>   IP addresses (source) **inside our** subnet
>    (128.3. * and 131.243.*) .

[image]

As an example 117.72.15.207 communicates (not subnet ip) with at least 3 **different** source addresses are in our subnet (131.243.92.10, 131.243.92.117 and 131.243.92.191). Please note that it communicates with 131.243.92.117 more than one with different source port addresses so it will count only one source address in output. i put a star to specify the condition.
we need the list of IP pairs who mets this condition

```
59.69.194.12 80 131.243.93.74 4492
59.79.35.247 80 131.243.94.123 1307
59.100.23.87 80 131.243.92.72 45577
*117.72.15.207 80 *131.243.92.10 451 
*117.72.15.207 80 *131.243.92.117 21071
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21072
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21073
*117.72.15.207 80 *131.243.92.191 9248
```

The output will be:

```
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.10 451 
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21071
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.191 9248
```

**Please comment if something is unclear.** Thanks...

Comment: So you want to do this in Perl... what do you have so far?  Update your post to include the code and specify what you don't understand.  Otherwise the question is likely to get closed.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, we extracted the Ip addresses and port numbers and sorted them from the traces, i have no knowledge about perl and not sure this can be done in other ways, so i posted here.

Comment: Generally SO is for asking specific questions, not for asking someone to write code for you.  You may find someone will take the time to write a complete solution for you, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, i understand your point of view, i'm not a new user. i appreciate any advise to get the solution, not need to be  a real solution, i didn't want to write in c++ just looking for other ways. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

my %ip_lookup;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($dest_ip, $dest_port, $source_ip, $source_port) = (split ('\s+', $_));
    $ip_lookup{$dest_ip}{$source_ip} = $_ unless $ip_lookup{$dest_ip}{$source_ip};
}

for my $dest_ip (keys %ip_lookup) {
    if (scalar(keys %{$ip_lookup{$dest_ip}}) >= 3) {
        print $_ for sort values %{$ip_lookup{$dest_ip}};
    }
}

__DATA__
9.69.194.12 80 131.243.93.74 4492
59.79.35.247 80 131.243.94.123 1307
59.100.23.87 80 131.243.92.72 45577
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.10 451 
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21071
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21072
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21073
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.191 9248
```

There are a few ways to do this in perl but the sample I've posted above is simple to explain.

First it's reading each line of the file in (I'm using the DATA handle but it'll work same with file), then splitting the line to get the different ip, port combinations.

Then it populates a multi-level hash unless this destination - source ip combination has been seen before (The differing ports point you made).

Finally it sorts and loops through checking if 3 or source IP entries have been made for each destination IP printing out the line if this is true.

This results in the output:

```
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.10 451 
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.117 21071
117.72.15.207 80 131.243.92.191 9248
```

which is what you required.

Comment: It probably needs to test for whether the IPs are inside or outside (as specified in the question - even thought the sample data doesn't require it).

Comment: In the question he actually states the format as Destination IP(sorted)- Dest_Port - Source IP- Source_Port. It's trivial to test the start of the IP to determine whether it's in or out of their subnet.